# Decimals to Integers

Tags: c#, integer, decimal, console-application

I'm having trouble with a particular homework assignment of mine. It almost seems impossible. The question goes like this...

"In the future, you may work with other programming languages that do not have a type like decimal which supports precise monetary calculations. In those languages, you should perform such calculations using integers. Modify the application to use only integers to calculate the compound interest. Treat all monetary amounts as integral numbers of pennies. Then break the result into its dollars and cents portions by using the division and remainder operations, respectively. Insert a period between the dollars and the cents portions when you display the results."

When I follow the directions and use integers I get these overflow errors before I can even divide anything out. Does anyone have any idea how to make this work? Here's the original code that needs to be modified...

```
    decimal amount; //amount on deposit at end of each year
    decimal principal = 1000; //initial amount before interest
    double rate = 0.05; //interest rate

    //display headers
    Console.WriteLine("Year{0,20}", "Amount on deposit");

    //calculate amount on deposit for each of ten years
    for (int year = 1; year <= 10; year++)
    {
        //calculate new amount for specified year
        amount = principal *
            ((decimal)Math.Pow(1.0 + rate, year));

        //display the year and the amount
        Console.WriteLine("{0,4}{1,20:C}", year, amount);
    }
```

This is the code I have so far...

```
        ulong amount; //amount on deposit at end of each year
        ulong principal = 100000; //initial amount before interest
        ulong rate = 5; //interest rate
        ulong number = 100;

        //display headers
        Console.WriteLine("Year{0,20}", "Amount on deposit");

        //calculate amount on deposit for each of ten years
        for (int year = 1; year <= 10; year++)
        {
            //calculate new amount for specified year
            amount = principal *
                ((ulong)Math.Pow(100 + rate, year));

            amount /= number;

            number *= 10;

            //display the year and the amount
            Console.WriteLine("{0,4}{1,20}", year, amount);
```

It gets some of the right numbers, but then starts spitting out zeros for some reason.

Comment: Part of good programming practice is choosing meaningful variable names. What purpose does "number" serve?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the values of `amount` and `number` each time through the loop, but I don't believe that's what you want to do here.  If you remove those assignments and change the parameters in your final `Console.WriteLine` call, (`amount / 100` and `amount % 100` will be helpful here) you should be able to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: We're thinking along the same lines, I was just going to make Mikey work a little harder for it. (It *is* his homework, after all.) I thought the question was quite generous when it said to "Treat all monetary amounts as integral numbers of pennies", a strong hint that the solution was something a bit more subtle than "Multiply every number in the original code by 100, do the math, and then divide the answer by 100 before printing it out".

Answer (score 0):

((ulong)Math.Pow(100 + rate, year)) Will grow way too fast 105^10 > ulong.

I think teacher ment for them to keep math.pow as a decimal.

```
amount = (ulong)(Math.Round(principal *
                Math.Pow((number + rate)/100.0, year),0));

            //display the year and the amount
            Console.WriteLine("{0,4}{1,17}.{2,-2}", year, "$" + (ulong)(amount / number), (ulong)(amount % number));
```

Question just says variables, not constants :) variables would all still be ulong